# What is "menu" in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, vocabulary, contemporary-latin, cibus

What would be a good Latin word for "menu" in the sense of a list of foods and drinks in a restaurant?
My dictionary suggests *index ciborum*, and another option would be to replace *index* with *tabula*.
Is there some widespread translation that would be a good choice?
I'm not sure if my dictionary offers and *ad hoc* translation or something that is actually in use.
Bonus points a classical or other early expression for a menu.

Comment: English didn't have the word *menu* before 1836. Ainsworth Eng.-Lat. (1780), suggests *tabula cibariorum.*  'Menu' is a diminutive, so perhaps *tabella* (a little page) *cibariorum* (of various foods).' Ainsworth Lat.-Eng. doesn't confirm. In fact *tabula* and *tabella* could be biscuits, or serving dishes, or the bill to be paid.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that both *index* and *tabula ciborum* work as calques but I can’t find any evidence for either in classical sources.  Indeed, I can’t find any information about whether there even were menus at *tabernae/popinae/cauponae*.  My understanding is that the foods were simply on display.

I also can’t find any evidence for *tabella cibariorum* but I did find a *wonderful* parallel in Greek: *γραμματειδιον*, also a diminutive, meaning little writing tablet.  Moreover, it is clearly being used to describe a menu, or at the least, a list of the food to be served, albeit at a dinner party:

> *Οτι εθος ην εν τοις δειπνοις τῳ εστιατορι κατακλιθεντι προδιδοσθαι
>   **γραμματειδιον** τι περιεχον των παρεσκευασμενων, εφ ῳ ειδεναι ο τι
>   μελλει οψον φερειν ο μαγειρος.*
>
> It was the custom at dinner parties for the host to be offered a
>   **little writing tablet** with a list of the foods prepared when he lay
>   down, so that he would know what food the cook was going to bring in.
>
> Athenaeus, *The Learned Banqueters*, 2.49d (please excuse the lack of
>   accents and breathings – it just takes too long to type them all in!)

My Latin suggestion is also from the dinner-party scene: *fercula*.  A *ferculum* was a tray used for carrying things, including meals and the plural, *fercula*, became a metonym for courses (of a meal).

> ***Fercula*** nunc audi …
>
> Now listen to the **courses** [I’m going to serve] …
>
> Juvenal, *Satires*, 11.64

> *multaque de magna superessent **fercula** cena*
>
> and many **courses** left over from the great dinner
>
> Horace, *Satires*, 2.6.24

Martial, complaining about his host at a dinner party who recited his own poems …

> *… dum **fercula** prima morantur*
>
> … while the first **course** awaits
>
> Martial, *Epigrams*, 3.50.5

> *sequens **ferculum** fuit scriblita frigida*
>
> the next **course** was a cold tart
>
> Petronius, *Satyricon*, 66

> *cenam ternis **ferculis** aut cum abundantissime senis praebebat*
>
> he served dinner with three **courses** or six at his most lavish
>
> Suetonius, *Lives of the Caesars: Augustus*, LXXIV

I think *fercula*/courses could stand alone for “menu”.  Or you could follow the Greek precedent and combine it with *tabella* to give *tabella ferculorum*/a little tablet of courses.

Comment: English borrowed the French *menu* and gave it a more specific meaning; you might do the same and take *grammātīdium, -ī* from the Greek.